# How do i check if an instance of the form already exists?

Tags: c#, winforms, plugins, rhino

Im developing a plugin for Rhino, and when i run the command starting plugin i carries out the following. It creates a splash form, which has a timer on it, and after 2sec i loads another form.

If i by mistake click the plugin-icon again, it creates another instance of the spash form, which loads the plugin again.

How do i prevent this?

This is the code that makes the form.

```
public override IRhinoCommand.result RunCommand(IRhinoCommandContext context)
            {

                Splash Splash = new Splash();
                Splash.Show();

                return IRhinoCommand.result.success;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public override IRhinoCommand.result RunCommand(IRhinoCommandContext context)
{
    if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<Splash>().Any())
    {
        new Thread(() => Application.Run(new Splash())).Start();
    }
    return IRhinoCommand.result.success;
}
```

Comment: When i try to use it through System.Windows.Forms it can't find the OfType property, how do i use it?

Comment: @Bildsoe: If you are on .NET 3.5 or later, make sure you have `System.Core` referenced and a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of the file. If you are not, loop through `Application.OpenForms` and check if any form is a `Splash` object.

Comment: @Bildsoe: The code starts a message-loop for the form on a separate thread and then displays it.

Comment: Ok, i just tried the code, and the forms is shown and then shortly after it disappears.

Comment: @Bildsoe: Ok, just call `Application.Run(new Splash());` without the thread. It will block until the form is closed. Is that what you require?

Comment: Is there any reason for doing the Application.Run instead of simply writing the following inside the if:

Splash Splash = new Splash();
Splash.Show();

Comment: @Bildsoe: There needs to be a message-loop. `Form.Show()` will return immediately.